# Is Exponential Map Lipschitz on Hadamard Manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lipschitz-functions

We know that in smooth Riemannian manifolds the exponential map is smooth and in the complete smooth manifolds with nonpositive sectional curvature (Hadamard manifolds) the exponential map is diffeomorphism. Now my question is as follows

When is the exponential map Lipschitz?

More precisely, is it true that in Hadamard manifolds (specially in manifolds with the constant nonpositive sectional curvature) exponential map is Lipschitz?

Comment: By Lipschitz do you mean $d_M(\exp x, \exp y) \le C |x-y|$, where $|\cdot|$ is the metric on the tangent plane?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, of course, and thank you for your comment.

Comment: Hint: Do you know the length of a circle formula in the hyperbolic plane? How does it compare with the Euclidean length?